# How to write to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Control Panel\\Desktop\\WindowMetrics from WinUI3 C# app

Tags: c#, registry, winui-3, winui

In my blank WinUI3 App I'm trying to change the value of the registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics\IconSpacing
```

At first glance it looks like it works. I'm opening the key and updatig the value to a new one. In my case to "-1129". The original value that is visible in the Registry Editor is "-1128". I also get the original value "-1128" in the first Debug output (only the first time the app runs).

```
RegistryKey windowMetricsKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Control Panel\\Desktop\\WindowMetrics", true);
Debug.WriteLine(windowMetricsKey.GetValue("IconSpacing")); // -1128 (only the first time the app runs, after that it's  -1129 
windowMetricsKey.SetValue("IconSpacing", "-1129");
Debug.WriteLine(windowMetricsKey.GetValue("IconSpacing")); // -1129
```

If I close and re-open my WinUI3 App the new value is preserved, but the value displayed in the Registry Editor never changes. It seems like I'm updating something else. There are no errors displayed in Visual Studio or any access related errors.

System restart does not change anything.

I've also tryed to use directly the `HKEY_USERS/{ Session Id }` instead of the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, but the result is the same. I'm updating something but the change is not available in the Registry Editor.

If I uninstall the app and re-install it the process is repeated. The first run I get "-1128" then the value gets updated to "-1129" but the Registry Editor shows the original value.

**Why is the registry key not updated and what I'm updating actually?** Can I update the "Real" `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` and how?

Thanks!

My System:

- Windows 10 Pro, 22H2, 19045.2364,
- Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4190.0,
- Visual Studio 2022 (Version 17.4.3),
- Latest WinUI3 (Windows App SDK 1.2),

Comment: Depending on how you package (or not), the app runs under registry virtualization https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/10/29/identity-registration-and-activation-of-non-packaged-win32-apps/ https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-disable-registry-file-redirection.html

Comment: Thanks I will take a look. My app is packaged as this is the default blank template.

Comment: So I checked your link but I did not get much useful information or maybe I do not understand it. Is there a way to avoid that virtualization?

Comment: Ok, so it's because your app is packaged, by defaut it lives in an AppContainer (https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/trust-identity-and-appcontainer-for-windows-apps/). Use a SparsePackage or run its full trust. Look at the second link or/and this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/flexible-virtualization

Comment: Thanks! The example in the second link was what I needed. I disabled RegistryWriteVirtualization and added unvirtualizedResources capability. The strange part was that the blank default template of VS was not able to handle those changes. The deployment of the app got broken after I added those and the required namespaces. I've created a new app with the Template Studio for WinUI and everything worked as expected. Do you mind adding and official answer so I can accept your solution? Btw all templates have fullTrust by default.

Comment: You should answer yourself with all these explanations that can be useful for others, I merely pointed in the right direction :-)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to happen because of the WoW64 registry redirection that inserts keys `Wow6432Node` into the keys tree. You may use [`OpenBaseKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.openbasekey?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0#Microsoft_Win32_RegistryKey_OpenBaseKey_Microsoft_Win32_RegistryHive_Microsoft_Win32_RegistryView_) and set the necessary registry view yourself to avoid it. Here's a sample:

```cs
using (RegistryKey root = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Registry64)) {
  // Use "root" instead of Registry.LocalMachine
}
```

Learn more about registry redirection [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/example-of-registry-reflection-and-redirection-on-wow64?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: Thanks I will try your suggestion and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Unfortunately, the behavior is not changed when I use your example. I've changed the LocalMachine with CurrentUser to match my case. I still get the wrong value. I've tried both Registry64 and Registry32 to see if it will make any difference but didn't had any luck. Btw, if the registry is redirected shouldn't the new key/value be visible under Wow6432Node in the Registry Editor. That's also not the case.